# How can I grant privilege's for file formats?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to grant privileges for file formats in an automated way, I just need to basic structure in how to do so. Based on the research I've done so far I think it should look like this:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myformat IN mydb.myschema TO myrole;
```

But I'm getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.

Error : "SQL compilation error: syntax error line 1 at position 34 unexpected 'in'."

thanks

Comment: you might not be able to upvote, but you can accept an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the following syntax

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FILE FORMAT mydb.myschema.myformat TO myrole;
```

Comment: thank you for this! Much appreciated. I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep points to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You need use the three-part qualifier instead of IN. You also need to specify that it's a file format, otherwise it will complain that it can't find the table with that name.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FILE FORMAT mydb.myschema.myformat TO myrole;
```

Comment: thank you for this! Much appreciated as well. I would upvote, but I don't have enough rep points to do so.